# Python Fast Implementation of Convolution/Cross-correlation of 3D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, convolution, numba, cross-correlation

I'm working on calculating convolutions (cross-correlation) of 3D images. Due to the nature of the problem, FFT based approximations of convolution (e.g. scipy fftconvolve) is not desired, and the "direct sum" is the way to go. The images are ~(150, 150, 150) in size, and the largest kernels are ~(40, 40, 40) in size. the images are periodic (has periodic boundary condition, or needs to be padded by the same image) since ~100 such convolutions has to be done for one analysis, the speed of the convolution function is critical.

I have implemented and tested several functions, including the scipy implementation of convolve with "method = direct", and the results are shown below. I used a (100, 100, 100) image and a (7, 7, 7) kernel to benchmark the methods here:

```
import numpy as np
import time
from scipy import signal
image = np.random.rand(Nx,Ny,Nz)
kernel = np.random.rand(3,5,7)

signal.convolve(image,kernel, mode='same',method = "direct")
```

took: 8.198s

I then wrote my own function based on array addition

```
def shift_array(array, a,b,c):
    A = np.roll(array,a,axis = 0)
    B = np.roll(A,b,axis = 1)
    C = np.roll(B,c,axis = 2)
    return C

def matrix_convolve2(image,kernel, mode = "periodic"):
    if mode not in ["periodic"]:
        raise NotImplemented
    if mode is "periodic":
        Nx, Ny, Nz = image.shape
        nx, ny, nz = kernel.shape
        rx = nx//2
        ry = ny//2
        rz = nz//2
        result = np.zeros((Nx, Ny, Nz))
        for i in range(nx):
            for j in range(ny):
                for k in range(nz):
                    result += kernel[i,j,k] * shift_array(image, rx-i, ry-j, rz-k) 
        return result


matrix_convolve2(image,kernel)
```

took: 6.324s

It seems in this case the limiting factor here is the np.roll function for periodic boundary condition, so I tried to circumvented this by tilling up the input image

```
def matrix_convolve_center(image,kernel):
    # Only get convolve result for the "central" block
    nx, ny, nz = kernel.shape
    rx = nx//2
    ry = ny//2
    rz = nz//2
    result = np.zeros((Nx, Ny, Nz))
    for i in range(nx):
        for j in range(ny):
            for k in range(nz):
                result += kernel[i,j,k] * image[Nx+i-rx:2*Nx+i-rx,Ny+j-ry:2*Ny+j-ry,Nz+k-rz:2*Nz+k-rz]
    return result

def matrix_convolve3(image,kernel):

    Nx, Ny, Nz = image.shape
    nx, ny, nz = kernel.shape

    extended_image = np.tile(image,(3,3,3))
    result = matrix_convolve_center(extended_image,kernel,Nx, Ny, Nz)
    return result

matrix_convolve3(image,kernel)
```

took: 2.639s

This approach gives the best performance so far, but still way too slow for actual application.

I did some research, and it seems using "Numba" could significantly improve the performance, or maybe write the same function in a parallel way could help too, but I'm not farmiliar with Numba, nor python parallelization (I had some bad experience with the `multiprocess` library... it seemed to skip iterations or suddenly stop sometimes)

Could you guys help me here? Any improvement would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you actually sure your implementation is more accurate than fft? You appear to be using sequential summation with a typical error scaling with the square root of the number of terms. fft according to wikipedia have a typical error scaling with the square root of the log of the number of samples. So I wouldn't be too surprised if that is more accurate given your problem size.

Answer (score 3):

This is far from conclusive but for the examples I checked `fft` is indeed more accurate than naive (sequential) summation. So, unless you have good reason to believe that your data are somehow different, my recommendation would be: Save yourself the trouble and use `fft`.

UPDATE: Added my own direct method, taking care to ensure it uses pairwise summation. This manages to be a bit more accurate than fft, but is still very slow.

Test script:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats, signal, fftpack

def matrix_convolve_center(image,kernel,Nx,Ny,Nz):
    # Only get convolve result for the "central" block
    nx, ny, nz = kernel.shape
    rx = nx//2
    ry = ny//2
    rz = nz//2
    result = np.zeros((Nx, Ny, Nz))
    for i in range(nx):
        for j in range(ny):
            for k in range(nz):
                result += kernel[i,j,k] * image[Nx+i-rx:2*Nx+i-rx,Ny+j-ry:2*Ny+j-ry,Nz+k-rz:2*Nz+k-rz]
    return result

def matrix_convolve3(image,kernel):

    Nx, Ny, Nz = image.shape
    nx, ny, nz = kernel.shape

    extended_image = np.tile(image,(3,3,3))
    result = matrix_convolve_center(extended_image,kernel,Nx, Ny, Nz)
    return result

P=0   # parity
CH=10 # chunk size

# make integer example, so exact soln is readily available
image = np.random.randint(0,100,(8*CH+P,8*CH+P,8*CH+P))
kernel = np.random.randint(0,100,(2*CH+P,2*CH+P,2*CH+P))
kerpad = np.zeros_like(image)
kerpad[3*CH:-3*CH,3*CH:-3*CH,3*CH:-3*CH]=kernel[::-1,::-1,::-1]
cexa = np.round(fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.ifftn(fftpack.fftn(fftpack.ifftshift(image))*fftpack.fftn(fftpack.ifftshift(kerpad)))).real).astype(int)
# sanity check
assert cexa.sum() == kernel.sum() * image.sum()

# normalize to preclude integer arithmetic during the actual test
image = image / image.sum()
kernel = kernel / kernel.sum()
cexa = cexa / cexa.sum()

# fft method
kerpad = np.zeros_like(image)
kerpad[3*CH:-3*CH,3*CH:-3*CH,3*CH:-3*CH]=kernel[::-1,::-1,::-1]
cfft = fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.ifftn(fftpack.fftn(fftpack.ifftshift(image))*fftpack.fftn(fftpack.ifftshift(kerpad))))

def direct_pp(image,kernel):
    nx,ny,nz = image.shape
    kx,ky,kz = kernel.shape
    out = np.zeros_like(image)
    image = np.concatenate([image[...,-kz//2+1:],image,image[...,:kz//2+P]],axis=2)
    image = np.concatenate([image[:,-ky//2+1:],image,image[:,:ky//2+P]],axis=1)
    image = np.concatenate([image[-kx//2+1:],image,image[:kx//2+P]],axis=0)
    mx,my,mz = image.shape
    ox,oy,oz = 2*mx-nx,2*my-ny,2*mz-nz
    aux = np.empty((ox,oy,kx,ky),image.dtype)
    s0,s1,s2,s3 = aux.strides
    aux2 = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(aux[kx-1:,ky-1:],(mx,my,kx,ky),(s0,s1,s2-s0,s3-s1))
    for z in range(nz):
        aux2[...] = np.einsum('ijm,klm',image[...,z:z+kz],kernel)
        out[...,z] = aux[kx-1:kx-1+nx,ky-1:ky-1+ny].sum((2,3))
    return out

# direct methods
print("How about a coffee? (This may take some time...)")

from time import perf_counter as pc

T = []
T.append(pc())
cdirpp = direct_pp(image,kernel)
T.append(pc())
cdir = np.roll(matrix_convolve3(image,kernel),P-1,(0,1,2))
T.append(pc())
# compare squared error
nrm = (cexa**2).sum()
print('accuracy')
print('fft   ',((cexa-cfft)*(cexa-cfft.conj())).real.sum()/nrm)
print('direct',((cexa-cdir)**2).sum()/nrm)
print('dir pp',((cexa-cdirpp)**2).sum()/nrm)
print('duration direct methods')
print('pp {} OP {}'.format(*np.diff(T)))
```

Sample run:

```
How about a coffee? (This may take some time...)
accuracy
fft    5.690597572945596e-32
direct 8.518853759493871e-30
dir pp 1.3317651721034386e-32
duration direct methods
pp 5.817311848048121 OP 20.05021938495338
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I understand that FFT convolve is faster, I didn't really get why it would be more accurate. Accuracy aside, there are other reasons that I would like to use summation in the analysis I'm doing, would you mind help me making the summation process more efficient?

Comment: @lxiangyun93 The wikipedia article explains why (pairwise summation structure; there is also an article on pairwise summation). I've added a direct method that uses pairwise summation. It is three times as fast as yours and even a bit more accurate than the fft based.