# How to implement correlation more efficiently?

Tags: numpy, opencv, matrix, graphics, computer-vision

The goal here is to implement the convolution operation for an image using numpy.

I was trying to implement a convolution function with padding options. However, my code uses two `for loops` to traverse rows and columns. Thus, extremely slow processing large image files.

```
def correlate(I, h, pad):
    top, bottom, left, right = pad
    tmp = zero_padding(I, top, bottom, left, right)

    print("padded shape:", tmp.shape)
    max_dim = max(len(tmp.shape), len(h.shape))
    while len(tmp.shape) < 3:
        tmp = tmp[..., np.newaxis]
    while len(h.shape) < 3:
        h = h[..., np.newaxis]

    if h.shape[-1] < I.shape[-1]:
        if (I.shape[-1] == 3) & (h.shape[-1] == 1):
                h = np.dstack([h,h,h])
        else:
            raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')  

    new_hight = tmp.shape[0] - h.shape[0] + 1
    new_width = tmp.shape[1] - h.shape[1] + 1
    result = np.ones((new_hight, new_width, tmp.shape[-1]))

    for ver in range(new_hight):
        for hor in range(new_width):
            block = get_block(tmp, h, ver, hor)
            mix = np.sum(np.sum(block*h, axis=0), axis=0)
            result[ver, hor] = mix
    return result
```

It took forever to process my (5000, 4000, 3) images.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/57967184/7207392

Comment: There are lots of libraries that have efficient implementations, don’t try to implement your own in Python, it’s never going to be fast.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Well, someone has to write these libraries.

Comment: Yes, they write them in C or C++ or Fortran.

Comment: @CrisLuengo ok, good point.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Interesting didn't know about fft convolution before. Need to do some research.

Comment: I posted an answer, for completeness... but I also wanted to say: almost every time I've tried to implement something I thought was pretty cunning in NumPy, I've later found an implementation of that thing in NumPy itself, or in SciPy (the latter especially if it's a multi-dimensional problem). About 2 hours ago I had this exact experience with `scipy.signal.spectrogram`.

Answer (score 0):

It's educational to implement this sort of thing on your own. But the main thing you learn is that it's really hard to (a) cover the edge cases and (b) make it fast.

You might want to try the correlation and convolution functions in the [`scipy.signal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html). For example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import correlate, convolve

a = np.random.random((100, 100, 3))
b = np.random.random((100, 100, 3))

corr = correlate(a, b, mode='same')
conv = convolve(a, b, mode='same')
```

You can pass a `method` argument to do it in the frequency domain, or there's also `fftconvolve()` (which `method='fft'` uses). You might want to time both options, because either one might be faster, depending on your data.